# How to extract file name from path/string?

Tags: c, filenames

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the answers seemed to help me:( I want to extract the file name from the path.

For example:

```
char *path = "C:\\Users\\Jared\\Desktop\\list.exe";

char *e_version = "list.exe";
```

I tried looping through an array and using strtok() to split the string up into tokens but no luck :( Does anyone have a function that can do this? I'm sorry for asking you to spoon feed me, but I can't find any clear examples.

Thank you, all help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on Windows, don't reinvent the wheel, use PathStripPath, or one of the umpteen other path manipulation functions which the Windows shell provides:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773756(v=vs.85).aspx

Here are the whole lot:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559(v=vs.85).aspx